# Combine two enums

Tags: scala, enums

How to combine two enums in scala?

```
object FilterDimensions extends Enumeration {
  type FilterDimensions = Value
  val Instance, Usage, Cost = Value

}

object Filter2Dimensions extends Enumeration {
  type Filter2Dimensions = Value
  val Instance, Savings, Coverage = Value

}
```

Output needs to be a **single enumeration** which contains **only the distinct values**

```
Enum - Instance, Usage, Costs, Saving, Coverage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

Even if you have an Enumeration A_1, with values B and C; and another Enumeration A_2 with values C and D, the correct 'name's are A_1.B, A_1.C, A_2.C, A_2.D. So they are completely unrelated types, there is no automatic way to discard what you think as a duplicated. Unless you base yourself on the String representation

Maybe you are thinking on the macroscopic problem wrong (or maybe you really need to do that you because someone defined like that and you have to do it). Have you though on having a common trait on both Enumerations? That would allow your methods to receive either Enumerations (not sure if it works, because you want the Enumeration.Value...)

Other option would be to have a 2in1 type. Either[FilterDimensions, Filter2Dimensions] could do it, but I'm almost sure [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats),[scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), or [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) have a more decent type

I wrote some stuff about enumerations on Scala, maybe you find it useful. It covers some alternatives to the native scala Enumerations, and maybe some of them have the features you need:

1. http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/
2. http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums-part2/